# What is wrong with the blockproc function in my matlab code?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to write the function `replace` that accesses every block in the image, keeps the first 2000 elements and sets the rest of them to zero. But every time I do that, I find this error message:

```
Error using blockproc>parse_inputs (line 997)
Invalid block function. BLOCKPROC expects the user function, FUN, to be a valid function handle.

Error in blockproc (line 219)
[source,fun,options] = parse_inputs(source,block_size,fun,varargin{:});

Error in blk2 (line 6)
J3 = blockproc(I3,[8 8],'dct2',f);
```

here is the code for the `replace` function:

```
function features = replace(block)
for( i = 2000:length(block.data) )
    % set each element to 0
   block.data(i) = 0
end
```

And my script which uses `replace`, `dct2` and `blockproc`:

```
I3 = imread('process/13.jpg');
figure;
imshow(I3);
f = @(block)replace(block.data);
J3 = blockproc(I3,[8 8],'dct2',f);
figure
imshow(J3);
imshow(log(abs(J3)),[]), colormap(jet), colorbar
J3(abs(J3) < 5) = 0;
%B=J;
%B(1:1) = 0;
[M N]=size(J3);
fun3=zigzag(J3);
in4=izigzag(fun3,M,N);
f = @(block)replace(block.data);
J22 = blockproc(in4,[8 8],'idct2',f);
figure
imshow(J22,[0 255]);
figure
imshow(log(abs(J22)),[]), colormap(jet), colorbar
```

[image: the input image]

Comment: Can you replace `block` with `block_struct` and report what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change few things until you get a running code. First, you should make some changes in `replace` function, since in yours the output is not defined. Additionally, the input argument should change to `data`, because you are passing `block.data` to it, which is a matrix:

```
function data = replace(data)
data(2000:end) = 0;
```

That said, this function does nothing in your example, since you are making 8x8 blocks.

If I understand correctly, you want to apply a 2-d discreet cosine transform to each block after applying `replace` to that block. If you take a look at [`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) you will see that the third input argument is supposed to be a function handle. In your case, `f` is an example of a function handle, but not exactly what you want. You can combine it with `dct2` and then pass the function handle to `blockproc`:

```
f = @(block) dct2(replace(block.data));
J3 = blockproc(double(I3),[8 8], f);
```

Note: You do not have to cast the image to `double`, but if you don't you will have higher loss of information.

Comment: You are welcome. If you are satisfied with the answer you may [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), so other people with a rather similar question will know there could be some useful information for them in the answer.